# justify-content in flexbox not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am new to flexbox and have an issue where justify-content is not working whenever I load my html page.

I am using the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
<style type="text/css">
    .headerElements {
        background-color: #000;
        height: 90px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between; 
        align-items: center;
    }
    .logo {
        width: 15%; 
        height: 100%;
    }
    .social {
        width:230px;
        height:50px;
    }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container" style="max-width: 600px; height: auto; margin: 0 auto;">
  <header class="headerElements">
    <figure class="logo">
      <img src="http://www.example.com/mailing/mailing/mailing_logo.png" style="width: 100%;">
    </figure>
    <div class="social">
      <a href=""><img src="http://www.example.com/mailing/mailing/mailing_06.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"> </a>
      <a href=""><img src="http://www.example.com/mailing/mailing/mailing_08.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"> </a>
      <a href=""><img src="http://www.example.com/mailing/mailing/mailing_10.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"> </a>
      <a href=""><img src="http://www.example.com/mailing/mailing/mailing_12.png" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"> </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what I get when I inspect the elements in Chrome:

```
div.m1581948eed9ce369 .m_701195392933853285headerElements {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 90px;
    display: flex;
}
```

justify-content and align-items are missing!!

What could I be doing wrong?

This is the current email I am receiving:

[image]

And this is how I expect to receive it:

[image]

Comment: seems ok! I have checked in Chrome. is this a part of an application ?, I have also edited your code, there was a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!! Yes, it's part of an application. This is the html that gets sent as an email from my php code. The problem is when I receive the mail, these two properties dissapear!!

Comment: well, it seems ok unless you give us a demo of what you have experienced.

Comment: I have added the pictures of how I am receiving the email, and how I expect to receive it. Could it be something outside of html or css?

Comment: use inline css instead and try, it seems your application is overriding something, <header class="headerElements" style="background-color: #000; height: 90px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">